# Can't push local Postgre database to Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

i have a problem getting my local database into Heroku.I'm currently working on building a Django web application and I tried to learn about getting local database to Heroku .I was trying to push my local Postgresql database with pg:push command then this error happen

```
pg_restore: error: unrecognized data block type (0) while searching archive
 !    pg_restore errored with 1
```

Any idea why is this happened ?

Comment: Double check the PostgreSQL versions, different versions can cause errors. Also make sure you use the `heroku pg:push` command (looks like did, good).

Comment: I get the same error using Postgres 12.4 locally and on Heroku. You can check the local version using `postgres -V`. You can check the Heroku version using `heroku pg:info --app app-name`.

Comment: I have this same issue while using version 13.2 on both.

Comment: Hi guys have you found any solution ? I have also encountered the issue but could  not  fix it. I have use psql 13.2 for both.

Comment: I have submitted a ticket to heroku for the 13.2 bug in which both local build and heroku postgres version are 13.2 but the error persists. I will post back here after the resolution of the ticket.

Comment: @KyleLaster any updates on how to fix this?

Comment: I had the same error with `heroku pg:pull`. Both push and pull are supposed to automate more manual processes. Even though `pg:pull` didn't work, the manual process did. Perhaps it will also work for `pg:push`: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Answer (score 0):

I'm a lazy programmer and efficient so this is much more easier rather than paying for AWS backup store them in excel sheets.
This save cost and not use PUSH: PULL which is not efficient.

Using CMD as ADMIN to insert Excel data to Heroku Postgres Database.

Follow INSTRUCTION

```
1. OPEN CMD AS ADMIN

2. heroku pg:sql postgresql-rugged-08088 --app sample

3. CREATE TABLE SERIAL_T (  id SERIAL , SERIAL VARCHAR(50),  USE INT,    DEVICES TEXT[], PRINTED BOOLEAN,  PRIMARY KEY (id))

4. \COPY SERIAL_T (SERIAL, USE, DEVICES, PRINTED) FROM 'C:\Users\PATH\EXCEL-03-27-2021.csv' DELIMITER ','CSV HEADER;
```

[image]

Comment: Same problem, anybodie found a solution?